# Optimal PNG images for Android

Tags: android

A long time ago I came across a video from one of the Android developers giving an introductory lecture about Android.  At one point during the lecture he mentions that Android is optimized for specifically formatted PNGs.  I can't find the video or any reference to the formatting.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the video and the formatting I was referring to in the OP:

The format is 565 formatted PNGs. The reference is at 0:04:17 here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zKy9iInXkY

It should be noted that this video is quite old.  I cannot find any references to the 565 formatting in the current Android documentation.  Formatting PNGs in 565 may be unnecessary now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to android .9 PNG's? if so here is a link

[Android PNG](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Android-9-Patch-Scaled-Png-Image-Guide/)

[.9 PNG for Themes youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lf1l9JV9JBw)

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the video, but I did find this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#drawables-from-images

Taken from the first line:

> Supported file types are PNG (preferred), JPG (acceptable) and GIF (discouraged).

Furthermore, if you look a little bit down, it goes into detail about NinePatchDrawable graphics, which are expandable PNG files and would explain why Android prefers PNG files to any other kind.

Comment: I've found the video!  The format is 516 formatted PNGs.  The reference is at 0:04:17 here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zKy9iInXkY

Comment: Excellent. I have not viewed the video, but do keep in mind it looks like it was uploaded 2 years ago and things might've changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/AndroidDev/android-ui-design-tips), which I felt were very helpful and a must-see for many intermediate Android developers. Although he doesn't talk exactly about what you are asking, it may still be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize png file size using OptiPng tool (find using search). And it appears that RGB565 mode is drawn faster than ARGB8888 when you use Canvas. See here: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/286-how-to-test-android-performance-using-fps. And png could be transparent :) That's all I know.